# What does echo $-1 display?

Tags: shell, echo, parameter

What does the output of `echo $-1`, `echo $-2`, `echo $-3`.. mean?

On one of my Linux boxes, it shows me:

```
echo $-1
imsBEl1
echo $-2
imsBEl2
```

And on another Linux box, it shows:

```
echo $-1
himBH1
echo $-2
himBH2
```

Are they mapping to some memory locations or some thing else?

Comment: The title is exhibiting the following problem in the sidebar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229363/205964

Comment: I added a proposed edit which tried to fix it, but I soon realized that it's only the sidebar that renders the MathJax, which means that when the title is on this page, it just gets unnecessary backslashes.

Answer (score 19):

`echo $-` prints options of the current shell (without `-` prefix).  `1` and `2` are additional unrelated tokens.

Answer (score 19):

POSIX defined [$-](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_02) as:

> -
>
> (Hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags (the single-letter
>   option names concatenated into a string) as specified on invocation,
>   by the set special built-in command, or implicitly by the shell.

So `$-` can be different base on your shell or how you invoke it.

`1` or `2` are separated token here. When the shell see unquote `$`, it will identify the start of any candidates for parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion. It saw `$-` and expanded it, left the rest unchanged.

You can see [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03) section for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Adding on to Miroslav's answer:

> `echo $-` prints options of the current shell (without `-` prefix). 1 and
>   2 are additional unrelated tokens.

This means that these are the options, for each machine respectively.

```
imsBEl
himBH
```

[I have researched the meaning of each flag](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) and compiled the meanings below, with minor paraphrasing.

> **-i**
>
> If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
>
> **-m**
>
> Monitor mode.  Job control is enabled.
>
> **-B**
>
> The shell performs brace expansion ([see Brace Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#BRACEEXPREF)). This
>   is on by default.
>
> **-s**
>
> If the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after option
>   processing, then commands are read from the standard input. This
>   option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an
>   interactive shell.
>
> **-E**
>
> errtrace
>
> **-l**
>
> Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
>
> **-h**
>
> hashall
>
> **-H History Expansion**
>
> This feature is enabled by default for interactive shells.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the existing answers, try `echo "${-1}"` and `echo "${-2}"` - you'll get a **"Bad substitution" error** because rather than using `-1` as a variable name the hyphen is used to [substitute a value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) if the variable name *before it* is undefined. For example:

```
$ unset foo
$ echo "${foo-bar}"
bar
$ foo=test
$ echo "${foo-bar}"
test
```